# What is the right equivalent for Java array of bytes in Swift?

Tags: java, swift, byte, checksum

I'm only starting to go into Swift development. I have the following method in Java:

```
  public static byte[] addChecksum(byte[]command, boolean isDeviceSendFormat) {
    int checksum = 0;
    int l = command.length;
    for (int i=0; i<l-2; i++) {

        if (i==1 && isDeviceSendFormat==true) {
            continue;
        }

        int val = command[i];
        if (val < 0) {
            val = 0x100 + val;
        }
        checksum += val;
    }

    if (l > 2) {
        if (isDeviceSendFormat == false) {
            command[l - 1] = (byte) (checksum % 0x100);  // LSB
            command[l - 2] = (byte) (checksum / 0x100);  // MSB
        }
        else {
            command[l - 2] = (byte) (checksum % 0x100);  // LSB
            command[l - 1] = (byte) (checksum / 0x100);  // MSB
        }
    }

    return command;
}
```

I need to translate to Swift and I'm having some problems, here is what I got so far:

```
func addCheckSum(bufferInput:[UInt8], isDeviceSendFormat: Bool) -> [UInt8]{
    var checksum: UInt8 = 0
    var length: Int = 0
    var iIndex: Int
    var bufferOutput: [UInt8]

    length = bufferInput.count        

    for (index, value) in bufferInput.enumerated() {
        if index < bufferInput.count - 2 {
            if value == 1 && isDeviceSendFormat {
                continue
            }

            var val:UInt8 = bufferInput[index]
            if (val < 0) {
                val = 0x100 + val //Error line
            }
            checksum = checksum + val
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error: `Integer literal '256' overflows when stored into 'UInt8'` on the commented line in the code above. How to translate this method from Java to Swift?

Comment: Why are you using `UInt8`? Java's `byte` is signed so wouldn't `Int8` be a better choice?

Comment: @Sweeper that what I seen that is used in Swift in tasks like this, for example here: https://www.bacpeters.com/2017/05/17/crc-16-in-swift-3-x/ or here: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/blob/master/Sources/CryptoSwift/Checksum.swift. But this is the whole point of the question, maybe Int8 is better but I don't know. This is the reason I ask the help of the experts here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my translation from your Java code into Swift:

```
public static func addChecksum(_ command: inout [UInt8], isDeviceSendFormat: Bool) -> [UInt8] {
    var checksum: UInt32 = 0
    let l: Int = command.count
    for i in 0..<l-2 {

        if i == 1 && isDeviceSendFormat {
            continue
        }

        let val = UInt32(command[i])
        //No need to modify `val` as it takes non-negative value when `command` is `[UInt8]`.
        checksum += val
    }

    if l > 2 {
        if !isDeviceSendFormat {
            command[l - 1] = UInt8(checksum % 0x100)  // LSB
            command[l - 2] = UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: checksum / 0x100)  // Next to LSB
        } else {
            command[l - 2] = UInt8(checksum % 0x100)  // LSB
            command[l - 1] = UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: checksum / 0x100)  // Next to LSB
        }
    }

    return command
}

//Assuming `command` is not too long as to make integer overflow in `checksum += val`.
```

---

Some notes:

- These 3 lines of your Java code:

  ```
  if (val < 0) {
      val = 0x100 + val;
  }
  ```

  convert the value -128...127, to 0...255 by adding `0x100`(=`256`) when the `val` is negative. So, `val` takes any value in 0...255, so, I choose `[UInt8]` for `command`. When you choose `UInt8`, the 3 lines above in Java is not needed in Swift.
- In your Swift code, you have chosen `UInt8` for `checksum` and `val`, but `int` in Java is 32-bit long and I choose `UInt32` for them. Assuming integer overflow may never happen, they take only non-negative values, so non-negative 32-bit long integer would be appropriate.

---

There's no direct equivalent of `byte[]` of Java in Swift. So, in some cases `[UInt8]` is more appropriate than `[Int8]`. And you can find many cases that Java's `byte[]` are translated into `Data` of Swift.

Comment: First thanks a bunch for this detailed explanation. Added a +1 for your effort. I'm going over you answer now trying to implement it in my project. Soon will give feedback.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, you helped me a lot.